# difference between Asynchronous and Synchronous in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

During my reading about Asynchronous Programming in .Net 4.5 `async` and `await` keywords
I read [Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) the following paragraph

> Processing Asynchronous Requests
>
> In web applications that sees a large number of concurrent requests at
>   start-up or has a bursty load (where concurrency increases suddenly),
>   making these web service calls asynchronous will increase the
>   responsiveness of your application. **An asynchronous request takes
>   the same amount of time to process as a synchronous request. For
>   example, if a request makes a web service call that requires two
>   seconds to complete, the request takes two seconds whether it is
>   performed synchronously or asynchronously**. However, during an
>   asynchronous call, a thread is not blocked  from responding to other
>   requests while it waits for the first request to complete. Therefore,
>   asynchronous requests prevent request queuing and thread pool growth
>   when there are many concurrent requests that invoke long-running
>   operations.

for the bold words, I couldn't understand them how An asynchronous request takes the same amount of time to process as a synchronous request?

**For example:**

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();
    //indeed you can do independent to the int result work here 

    //and now we call await on the task 
    int result = await longRunningTask;
    //use the result 
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public async Task<int> LongRunningOperation() // assume we return an int from this long running operation 
{
    await Task.Delay(1000); //1 seconds delay
    return 1;
}
```

What I understand that `LongRunningOperation()` starts execution from the first line calling here `Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();` and returns value once calling `await`,
so from my point of view asynchronous code faster than synchronous, is that right?

### Another question:

What I understand that the main thread working on executing `MyMethod()` not blocked waiting for `LongRunningOperation()` to be accomplished but it returns to thread pool to serve another request. so is there another thread assigned to `LongRunningOperation();` to execute it?

**If yes** so what is the difference between Asynchronous Programming and Multithreading Programming ?

**Update:**

let's say that code becomes like that:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
    {
        Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();
        //indeed you can do independent to the int result work here 
        DoIndependentWork();
        //and now we call await on the task 
        int result = await longRunningTask;
        //use the result 
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public async Task<int> LongRunningOperation() // assume we return an int from this long running operation 
    {
        DoSomeWorkNeedsExecution();
        await Task.Delay(1000); //1 seconds delay
        return 1;
    }
```

In this case , will `LongRunningOperation()` be executed by another thread during `DoIndependentWork()` execution?

Comment: You are missing some important basics. Hard to give a good answer. You need a tutorial. Find out what await does.

Comment: It's always going to take the same amount of time to perform work, asynchronous code simply performs the work in a different order.  The stuff that takes longer may get offloaded to another thread.  So the task being performed will still take time, but the application simply isn't waiting for the task to complete.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The asynchronous operations aren't faster. If you wait for 10 seconds asynchronously (i.e. `await Task.Delay(10000)`) or synchronously (i.e. `Thread.Sleep(10000)`) **it would take the same 10 seconds**. The only difference would be that the **first would not hold up a thread while waiting but the second will**.

Now, if you fire up a task and don't wait for it to complete immediately you can use the same thread to do some other work, but it doesn't "speed up" the asynchronous operation's run:

```
var task = Task.Delay(10000);
// processing
await task; // will complete only after 10 seconds
```

About your second question: `Task.Delay` (like other truly asynchronous operations) doesn't need a thread to be executed and so [there is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). `Task.Delay` is implemented using a `System.Threading.Timer` that you fire up and it raises an event when it's done, in the meantime it doesn't need a thread because there's no code to execute.

So when the thread that was running `MyMethod` reaches the `await longRunningTask` it is freed (as long as `longRunningTask` hasn't completed yet). If it was a `ThreadPool` thread it will return to the `ThreadPool` where it can process some other code in your application.

---

Regarding the update the flow would be so:

- `MyMethod` starts processing
- `LongRunningOperation` starts processing
- `DoSomeWorkNeedsExecution` is executed on the calling thread
- An `await` is reached in `LongRunningOperation` and so a hot task is returned.
- `DoIndependentWork` is executed by the same calling thread (`LongRunningOperation` is still "running", no thread is needed)
- An `await` is reached in `MyMethod`. If the original task completed the same thread will proceed on synchronously, if not then a hot task would be returned that would complete eventually.

So the fact that you're using `async-await` allows you to use a thread that would otherwise be blocked waiting synchronously to executed CPU-intensive work.

Comment: Thanks l3arnon for your quick reply,
"in the meantime it doesn't need a thread because there's no code to execute." for this, assume that longRunningTask has large amount of code to be executed so, another thread rather than the main thread will be assigned to it?

Comment: @AbrahamJosef If that work is CPU intensive (i.e. not asynchronous)   then there are 2 options. If it's before the `await` it will run on the calling thread. If it's after then it will run on a thread according to the `SynchronizationContext` (usually there isn't one, so a thread pool thread would be used).

Comment: @AbrahamJosef If the work is asynchronous (e.g. I/O) then no thread is needed.

Comment: @i3arnon Can I ask if possible for you to explain that which one is more beneficial?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani an asynchronous operation compared to a synchronous one? If it's possible asynchronous is usually preferable, but only if the operation is inherently asynchronous itself (e.g. I/O)

Answer (score 5):

Consider the difference between:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

and

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

both will take one second to run. However in the former case the current thread will be blocked (and all its resources useless) while in the latter case the current thread can do something else that's useful (eg. serving another request).

Asynchronicity is not about speeding up individual sequences of instructions, but being able to do things when synchronous code would block.

Re. **Another question**

The thread(s) freed up will be used for other things; there will be no thread assigned until the operation is completed. This is possible becuase the underlying OS is itself asynchronous. In the example above a timer is used which is signalled for a thread to pick up when a thread is free, rather than a thread stopped for an internal.

Answer (score 2):

(building upon I3arnon's answer)

It's not absolutely true that synchronous operations and operations using `async-await` will, overall, take the same time.

There's some extra logic involved in `async-await`. Checks of completed awaiters and a state machine are involved. This makes some asynchronous operations take more time than the corresponding synchronous operation.

On the other hand, most operations suited for `async-await` are naturally asynchronous and there is some extra processing involved to make it look and feel synchronous. In these cases the asynchronous operation is takes less time than the synchronous counterpart.

The quote on the question is related to web applications. For web applications, asynchronous operations are more about serving the maximum number of requests on an acceptable time than saving of a few microseconds of each request. On the other hand, if a context switching is involved it ends up take more time and that's why using `Task.Run` in a web application does more bad than good to the application.

If you want to learn more about `async-awit`, read the articles on [my `async-awit` curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).